# Htaccess ignore vanity sub folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need help with solving an htaccess problem

Lets say I have a website called www.mysite.com

I want www.mysite.com/{VARIABLE}/home to load www.mysite.com/home regardless of what {VARIABLE} is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.+)/home$ /home [L]
```